# Do questions with bounty have more resistance to closing?

Tags: discussion, support, bounties, closed-questions

Do questions with bounty have more resistance to closing? Do you think they should or not?

Answer (score 9):

Questions with a bounty are immune from closure except by moderators, who can refund the bounty and close the question.  Note the [question/answer from Jeff here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/why-cant-we-close-questions-with-bounties/27103#27103)

Answer (score 2):

I never consider closing bounty questions.  It takes 2 days before they can set a bounty so the egregious questions are already weeded out.

Comment: Not always the case:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8026572/looking-for-a-gsm-modem-advice
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8006585/chrome-html5-maximized-video-full-tab-not-fullscreen