# Should questions with bounties have same `user shared attempt` requirements (regarding downvoting and closure)?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, bounties, down-votes

I saw [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100195/do-questions-with-bounty-have-more-resistance-to-closing) but didn't think it addressed this question.

I'm relatively new to being an answer producer at Stack Overflow. I've learned that answering possible duplicates (instead of voting for closure) or answering questions where the user has not given enough info - or showed no attempt in solving can often earn downvotes and sometimes a 'tsk tsk' from some S.O. user or another. Despite the dopamine hit that comes with earning a little green reputation boost, I get that the goal is to keep the content as high quality and non-duplicitous as possible - AND I get that the goal is to help others learn, not just feed them a copy/paste answer.

THAT SAID, in the last half dozen bounty questions I've answered, I'm surprised at how little information was given, how little research was done and how absent the user attempt generally is. Normally I'd vote to close those... but there is that nice fat bounty.

The bounty seems to imply, to me anyways, that the user is 'paying' for special treatment. I don't vote to close those ill-formed, ill-researched and blatant 'write me code for me' questions because I figure someone hungry will go the extra mile to get the extra reputation.

Do you expect the same considered, researched and partially attempted question from bounties as you do from any other question? Do you vote to close them?

Hope this isn't asking opinions, as much as a general consensus.

Comment: At least for me personally, no, the bounty only pays for the advertisement, it doesn't pay for getting away with skipping the quality rules. i vote accordingly, and bookmark it if i feel it should be closed to revisit it after the bounty period. Usually i'd suggest a mod flag, but, it's unlikely one would be processed before the bounty ends anyway.

Comment: People can't actually vote to close bountied questions. So even while they may expect the same standards, the bounty is preventing close votes (and any existing ones are aging away during the bounty period).

Comment: @gnat - a little. Actually another link on that page partially answered it - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140206/how-to-prevent-your-question-being-closed-just-post-a-bounty-on-it

Comment: I think the answers to that question were a whole lot more relevant back then than they are today. The quantity of incoming questions and flags in the queues are both much larger now

Comment: top answer in that another link indeed seems to address this best, "If a question that should be closed receives a bounty, it means the moderation has failed already. The question was then open for at least 2 days, in which it should have been closed..."

Comment: @Tinkeringbell - thanks, I should have researched that first. I suppose it has more to do with quality expectations for bountied vs non-bountied. I know most SO veterans would say the expectation should be the same, but I'm more likely to give those more leeway. Wondered if others were like that as well

Comment: In [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) the consensus seems to be: if the bounty just started, custom flag for a mod. Otherwise let it run to completion and close vote after the grace period ended.