# What happens if I delete a question with a bounty?

Tags: discussion, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

If I have put a bounty on my question and then decide none of the answers are good enough, can I just delete the question?  Will I get my reps back for the bounty?

Comment: Direct link to relevant part:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/why-cant-we-close-questions-with-bounties/27103#27103

Answer (score 4):

Questions with a bounty cannot be closed, or deleted. In exceptional circumstances moderators can refund the bounty, and the question can be then closed, or deleted according to the normal rules.

It should be pointed out that a question with answers cannot be deleted by the original poster. The community can once it is closed and over a certain age and the moderators can at any point.

Comment: What if question with bounty suddenly receives six spam flags? From what I know, this alone will make it deleted automatically..

Comment: Normally, the question would be deleted, but not when there is a bounty. (As far as I understand it.)

Comment: Would be nice if we can test such thing.. :)

Comment: Yes, it would be. This also takes me to another question.