# What should be done when a question ask something that is covered by a FAQ question, but not explicitly covered by that question?

Tags: support, meta-faq

I am using a question as example, but I am not suggesting that the question needs to be re-opened. This question is about what needs to be done, if something needs to be done, after the new question is closed as duplicate of a question tagged [faq](/questions/tagged/faq).

[What happens if I delete a question with a bounty?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115281/what-happens-if-i-delete-a-question-with-a-bounty) has been closed as duplicate of [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) Effectively what asked has been already answered in that [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) question, even though the used sentences ("Bounty questions cannot be closed. However, diamond moderators can refund bounties, which would then allow it to be closed, migrated, or deleted.") could leave some doubts about the fact they apply to the specific question. The first sentence just make reference to questions with bounty, which cannot be closed, while the second sentence says that once the bounty is refunded, the question can be migrated, deleted, or closed; from that, I assume that (without the bounty being refunded) the question cannot be migrated, deleted, or closed (even if the first sentence talks of closing a question with a bounty).

When are there questions that make you think the answers for a question tagged [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) should be rephrased to be clearer, or be expanded to include a specific case, should the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) answers be edited, or left as they are? In which cases should the answers be edited? Do we decide basing on the number of new questions asked about the same topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) is lacking information that *should* be in the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq), then it should be fixed as soon as possible. There's no need to wait for "enough instances", the point is clarity so that people aren't forced to make guesswork when reading the post.

In your above example, the first sentence could probably be as follows. One might say it's redundant, but it's *clearer*. Instructional writing tends to be redundant to begin with, haha.

> Bounty questions cannot be closed, migrated, or deleted.

Technically, there is already a direct implication - migration and deletion are both primarily possibly *after* closure, as they are respectively a form of closure and something that requires closure to happen on the community moderation side.

That implication is not relevant to clarity, though, so making the revision makes it much simpler to understand. A much more major thing to look at, for example, would be the number of times we link people who ask about "Sorry, we're not accepting *answers* from this account" to the question we have that talks about "Sorry, we're not accepting *questions* from this account". The rules are all the same for both, but the actual [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) doesn't even mention the answers version, to my recollection.

Answer (score 4):

I've had the following situation come up two or three times now:

1. I see an MSO question about a topic for which an [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) entry exists
2. I open up the FAQ entry in preparation for voting to close
3. I notice that the information the asker is looking for is actually not present in the entry (or, in one case, was present but obsolete)
4. I edit the entry to include that information
5. I vote to close the question that started it all

With MSO being the network's support site, maintaining a comprehensive FAQ and then pointing users to that FAQ should be encouraged.