# Why cannot this question with an open bounty be closed?

Tags: discussion, bounties

I have seen a number of questions like:

> "Do this work for me please" or without "please"

If such a question doesn't have a bounty, I can downvote it if I want or flag it for closing. But if it has a bounty, then it's protected.

Why?

To be clear, I have nothing against "do-it-for-me" questions in real life, but if it's not allowed on Stack Overflow without a bounty why is it allowed with it?

*Update:*
And you can probably close / put on hold such a question after the bounty time is over..

Examples of such questions that I have flagged:

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19065751/simple-python-ormapper-requiring-no-explicit-mapping-in-the-persistent-classes) - was put on hold and deleted by TS

[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15744646/nonparametric-multinomial-regression-in-r) - was put on hold and deleted by TS

[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18985053/rest-api-best-practices-for-returning-assigned-resources) - flag was declined

[4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19060033/fusioncharts-heatmap-display-zeroes-instead-of-blanks-missing-values) - flag was declined

[5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19067911/can-we-access-a-vmx-appliance-by-a-name) - flag was declined

[6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19055908/how-to-use-different-icon-on-app-store-and-devices-homescreen-for-applications) - flag was declined

[7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19036765/configuring-intern-to-setup-teardown-my-server-mock) - flag was marked as helpful

[8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16651364/nexus-4-android-tap-to-scroll-issue) - flag was declined

[9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19007840/what-are-some-available-architectures-for-caching-data-used-for-dropdowns-or-oth) - flag was marked as helpful

[10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18735996/requirejs-rjs-how-to-break-the-build-into-several-files) - flag was declined

[11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19082076/when-i-set-up-hadoop-what-permissions-are-needed-on-the-underlying-filesystem) - flag was declined

Comment: Probably something to do with the user placing the bounty losing the rep already and then not being able to assign it to new answers as the question is closed. Just spit-balling though, someone that actually truly knows will likely come along shortly.

Comment: @Fluffeh maybe - but not agree with it. Cause the idea is to have clean SO forum. And if you pay with reputation than you can post what you want?

Comment: Just went and played with a question, I can vote to close (though I didn't click confirm, but it popped up) and I can vote up and down. Are you sure you can't perform those actions?

Comment: @Fluffeh You should have clicked to confirm...

Comment: @Fluffeh I havent 3k on SO - so if I see such a question I can downvote - if on bounty question - but cannot flag off-topic on it

Comment: You can't do it, because of exactly where @Fluffeh said.  The rep has been paid, so they system is designed to prevent the OP from losing the rep for no reason.  The appropriate action is to flag for mod attention.  The mod can cancel the bounty, refund the rep, and close the post.

Comment: How often do poor questions get a bounty on them? How many users that will post such a question will have enough reputation to post a bounty in the first place?

Comment: @Oded - do you want some examples?

Comment: @Bart I did click with the voting, then corrected it, but I wasn't going to cast a close vote on a question just to double-check. I assume that is when the action is rejected?

Comment: @MikroDel - examples are always welcome. We value facts :)

Comment: @Oded http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19065751/simple-python-ormapper-requiring-no-explicit-mapping-in-the-persistent-classes

Comment: So, why didn't you downvote that and add a comment?

Comment: downvoted already now also post a comment

Comment: @Oded - do you agree with me that its not good question with bounty or not?

Comment: And this is **one** example. This is not normally a problem - if this were to become a big issue, then we would need to address it within the system. As it stands, flagging for moderator attention is the right thing to do.

Comment: I certainly agree - it is a resource question and I am certain the OP knows it shouldn't have been asked in the first place.

Comment: @Oded - you wanted examle - I have found it for you in 90 sec. It cannot be **big** problem, cause we have not a gib number of questions with a bounty

Comment: That's my point. It is something to be handled through moderator flags.

Comment: @Oded - and my post here was to understand the logic of this option. Bad questions with bounty are allowed

Comment: @Odded - ok thanks. I have flagged it already. And what happened with bounty (rep points) if moderartor put in on hold?

Comment: The question was deleted and the reputation refunded.

Comment: @Oded - you can post you comments here as an answer and I will accept it - and we have one more question with an answer here =)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140206/how-to-prevent-your-question-being-closed-just-post-a-bounty-on-it (good answer there, explaining the reasoning)

Comment: @Oded Understood :) I just flagged another *example* (fortunately you are right this is another *exception*) of a question asking for code/resources, with 4 votes for closing (included mine), and now protected with a bounty.

Comment: @Oded - how do you think after this discussion - will it be ok if I start the question here on MSO with feature - some kind of queue for the bounty qeustions? Before it will be bounty question it should be reviewed by SO users. Cause this defence mechanism - 2 days after question start - not really works. I have flagged 11 questions and half was closed/put on hold/edited.

Comment: @MikroDel - You can always make a feature-request. Whether it will be implemented depends on many things (community reception, effort/benefit ratio etc). But in this case, consider that perhaps your have been a bit overzealous in your flagging? Not every question with a bounty is an attempt to keep it open.

Comment: @Oded sure not every question. Overzealous - but my more than 500 flags helped also to make it some better )

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can still downvote a question with a bounty and should do so. If a question is something that obviously doesn't belong, you should also flag it for moderator attention (using Other and citing bounty abuse).

Moderators will be able to close & delete such a post (deletion would refund the lost reputation to the user offering the bounty).

Abusing bounties in this way is extremely rare - most people value their reps and the quality of questions on Stack Overflow and as such, though this happens on occasion, it is not something we feel needs to be automated - our [human exception handlers](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/) can and should deal with these on a case-by-case basis.

---

Mad Scientist [answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/140209/140505) on [How to prevent your question being closed? Just post a bounty on it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140206/how-to-prevent-your-question-being-closed-just-post-a-bounty-on-it):

> If a question that should be closed receives a bounty, it means the moderation has failed already. The question was then open for at least 2 days, in which it should have been closed. For this reason this situation is relatively rare, most questions are closed earlier.

Comment: And now after the question is deleted someone may ask why the user has a *Promoter* badge when he has not [offered any bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/users/118587/grzegorz-oledzki?tab=bounties&sort=offered) yet.

Comment: @hims056 this badge should be "Bad question promoter" =)

Comment: @hims056 - Unless we can _prove_ bad faith in this case, I would tend to keep to the "badges are not revoked" rule.

Comment: @Oded - Correct. He didn't offer the bounty to get the badge.

Comment: For your information about only **one** example - I will update my answer with 10 more

Comment: @MikroDel - by all means. By doing the work and **proving** that there is a problem, you are well on the way of making a change in how things work. Good job.

Comment: @Oded - ok thanks =) I like to refactor ) Take a look at my updated question

Comment: Heh, "for this reason this situation is relatively rare" --- not that rare when there are 80k+ questions in the close vote queue.

Comment: @Juhana - I will take care about close queue after I fave 3k )

Answer (score 15):

Keep in mind that a bounty cannot be started **until two days after the question was asked.**  So it's not like a user can post a crap question and quickly "protect" it by placing a bounty on it. If the question is not viable, it most likely would have been closed long before it become eligible for a bounty.

We cannot close 'featured' questions as readily as "normal" questions. **Bounties are a contract with the participants** who were promised a reward for the top answer. Bounties are paid up front and are non-refundable under most circumstances. We don't want to create a situation where promises are made (and the question 'featured') just to have it CLOSED through a slow accretion of votes because the problem wasn't egregious enough to close it quickly.

I think allowing closures during a bounty is **more likely to be gamed in the *other* direction** — get your answer with a promise of a bounty, and then get your question closed so you don't have to pay it.

**Closing 'Featured' Questions**
Automated processes aren't always perfect. If a poorly-asked question gets past the first two days, becomes 'protected' by a bounty, and absolutely can't wait to be closed *after* the seven days (max), simply 'flag' it for moderator attention. It's an exceptional situation that is easily handled by Moderators. That's why we call them "exception handlers."

Comment: "If the question is not viable, it most likely would have been closed long before it become eligible for a bounty." - strongly disagree. Except for the "obvious nonsense" questions, it can easily take some days (of requests for clarification in comments, question revisions, maybe even more notably further inquiries and discussion by the OP on posted answers) during which the actual intention of the OP is gradually revealed, which can shed an entirely new light on a seemingly well-written question.

Answer (score 7):

Not an answer to this question exactly, more a response to your examples...

**There's no "Asks folks to do something for him" close reason.** Why not? Because that would mean the vast majority of the questions on SO should be closed - including quite a few rather useful ones.

I *think* the problem you're suggesting is one involving the asker asking for an exceptional amount of effort, which can be a bit off-putting... But then again...

**Why on earth would anyone offer a bounty if they didn't expect someone to do something to earn it?**

I don't particularly like bounties; I don't blame you if you don't like them either. But like 'em or not, [this was pretty much the exact reason for their creation](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/reputation-bounty-for-unanswered-questions/):

> Stack Overflow already works well for smaller, simpler questions. We’re hoping the new question bounty will improve answer quality on those tougher questions that aren’t so easy to answer. But they do require a bigger commitment from both the asker and the answerer — **you must be willing to slice off a piece of your own reputation and bestow it upon the person who is best able to answer your question.**

If you're gonna be shocked every time you see a "much effort required" question with a bounty on it, you're probably best off not looking at bountied questions.

---

Here's my take on the examples:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19065751/simple-python-ormapper-requiring-no-explicit-mapping-in-the-persistent-classes tool-rec question; closed and deleted.
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15744646/nonparametric-multinomial-regression-in-r - tool-rec question; closed and deleted. (this might actually be appropriate for Cross Validated; not sure)
- [How should I represent many-to-many class and professor relationship using a REST API and Zend Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18985053/rest-api-best-practices-for-returning-assigned-resources) overly subjective at first glance, but reasonably specific upon further reading. Edited title.
- [FusionCharts HeatMap: Display zeroes instead of blanks/missing values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19060033/fusioncharts-heatmap-display-zeroes-instead-of-blanks-missing-values) - a specific question on a specific tool; now self-answered by the asker. Potentially useful to others with the same problem.
- [Can we access a VMX appliance by a name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19067911/can-we-access-a-vmx-appliance-by-a-name) a specific question on a specific tool.
- [How to use a different icon for the App Store and device's home screen in applications with image assets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19055908/how-to-use-a-different-icon-for-the-app-store-and-devices-home-screen-in-applic) - a specific question on a specific tool.
- [Configuring Intern to setup/teardown my server mock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19036765/configuring-intern-to-setup-teardown-my-server-mock) - problematic in that the asker does not go into detail on where he's running into trouble. I'm not familiar enough with testing node.js to know if the problem should be obvious or not though. Posted a comment requesting clarification.
- [Nexus 4 / Android tap to scroll issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16651364/nexus-4-android-tap-to-scroll-issue) specific question on a specific problem (one probably familiar to many Android users). Now answered.
- [How can I improve the performance of static data caching in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19007840/what-are-some-available-architectures-for-caching-data-used-for-dropdowns-or-oth) overly broad. Closed, edited by the author, edited by me, reopened.
- [How to break the build into several files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18735996/how-to-break-the-build-into-several-files) specific question regarding specific tool.
- [When I set up Hadoop, what permissions are needed on the *underlying* filesystem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19082076/when-i-set-up-hadoop-what-permissions-are-needed-on-the-underlying-filesystem) specific (if someone confusing) question on specific tool. Now answered.

Two things I found very irritating while reviewing these:

1. critical comments from folks who made no effort to understand the problem ("you question is not SO conform" is... not a very specific criticism. Can you point to an entry in /help that implies this? Perhaps a discussion on meta? Or just state what you find problematic in the question?).
2. Flags that consist of little or nothing beyond ""Do it for me" question". What is that supposed to mean? I'm plenty familiar with questions from folks who've done little more than post an assignment or spec document into the question; none of these matched that pattern. If Stack Overflow can't be used to find solutions to *specific programming problems*, then what exactly is the point?

Comment: hmmmm... there is nevertheless a difference between 1) *"much effort required"*, which means for me efforts, lot of research, technical skills...  (**from the asker first** and then from those who reply) and 2) *here are my requirements, I'm a slacker, so here some bounty and do my job please*.  Your answer seems to me too simplistic. Don't you think?

Comment: To be clear, what I mean is while what you say is right, there are some exceptions that should be handled.

Comment: @Chris: simplistic? Did you look over those examples? Reading the discussions as they crop up is making me want to tear my hair out. Asking a straight-forward "How can I do X?" question shouldn't require a whole lot in the way of supporting data - explain the problem, be specific on where you're having trouble, and what results you're after. Trivial questions where the answer is easily found on Google (or especially on Stack Overflow) are a problem, but... They're not really represented here.

Comment: First, thanks for the reply and I'm sorry but, due to translation and my English skills, I am not always sure to understand *exactly" the meaning of all what I read. I don't think that the problem is *the trivial questions where the answer is easily found on Google (or especially on Stack Overflow)*, the problem is poor question (too broad, not clear..) that are *protected* by a bounty. If some of the questions given in example have been closed (and from what I see, some of the others could be closed too), it means that the OP question make sens.

Comment: And again, while I think you are right in your answer, I think  (maybe I'm wrong)  that your **last sentence in your answer** (before the edit) is not appropriate.

Comment: It's what's known as a rhetorical question, @Chris. Collecting answers to specific programming problems *is* the point of Stack Overflow - that's why I get so frustrated when I see questions that *are* specific, on-topic and answerable shut down.

Comment: Do you mean generally that there are 2 kind of standrards for a good question on SO. First for normal question - we all know them. The second one - for questions with bounty?

Comment: OK I understand your point of view. Personally, I also make a difference between on-topic, specific questions with or without any efforts from the OP.

Comment: @MikroDel: the bounties are irrelevant to me. Either a question is on-topic and answerable, or it's not.

Comment: Thank you for you answers and time you invest to explain it all!

Comment: "Effort" can be incredibly hard to judge, @Chris. I don't ask many questions, but I *use* an awful lot of them. If someone asks a simple question because they can't find an answer using Google, they're not putting a tremendous amount of effort in... But I'm putting far less in by using the answer to their question after I find it on Google.

Comment: You are right, "Effort" can be incredibly hard to judge. It's why in lot of case, technical skills on the subject are necessary to *try* to judge them. I don't want to close all questions with bounty, but a question like the one I flagged this afternoon (which has been closed), *making me want to tear my hair out*, too. We can not all agree on everything. In any case, Thank you for your viewpoint developed here.

Answer (score 3):

The system prevents closing a question with a bounty on it so the user doesn't lose the rep. That being said, you can go through all the steps to close it but you actually can't close it which doesn't make much sense to me. I suggest that when a question has a bounty on it the *close* option is removed and just the *flag* option remains. [Moderators have the ability](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/how-can-we-close-questions-with-bounties/27103#27103) to close a question with a bounty and refund any rep.