# Can't close questions with a bounty?

Tags: discussion, bounties, vote-to-close

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can we close questions with bounties?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/how-can-we-close-questions-with-bounties)

I voted to close [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376524/java-code-coverage-tools-which-support-source-line-exclusions) because it was asking if there were any products out there  that support a certain feature and answers for questions like that tend to get heated.  I was surprised to get a message back saying that questions with a bounty (this one had a bounty) can't be closed.

Really? A question that for whatever reason is not appropriate can stay open if someone puts a bounty on it?

If we really feel the question should be closed do we have to flag for moderator attention?

Edit:  OK, so that's confirmed, but can any moderators out there give a hint as to the criteria they'd use to decide whether to override the bounty and close such a question?