# Confusing link from achievements drop down

Tags: bug, notifications, achievements-dialog

I've received notification several times via the achievements drop down menu that I've received an up vote (5 rep).  When I follow the provided link, however, I see that neither the question nor any of the answers are mine. I finally figured out that my original question was closed as a dup of the question I was sent to.

I get that we want to route folks away from duplicate questions and towards the original questions, but I think in this case it makes sense to go to the actual question for which I had received the rep.

EDIT: Here's [the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155897/cant-close-questions-with-a-bounty) in question.

Comment: Yeah, the achievements links should use `?noredirect=1` like the inbox items do.

Comment: @Tim it's not needed for questions closed as dupe, just checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16046200/why-java-doesnt-provide-default-constructor-if-class-has-parametrized-construc/16046306#16046306) and never got redirected. Maybe migrated?

Comment: @ShadowWizard It is, just [not all users are automatically redirected](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125220/automatically-redirect-anonymous-user-from-unanswered-duplicate-question-to-corr). The OP might have gotten reputation on a site where they weren't yet logged in.

Comment: As per [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/209337/221351) *"When a question is closed as a duplicate of another one, anonymous users are redirected to the "original" question"*  so this should not happen for Logged-in users

Comment: This question was migrated, I think, as part of the MSO split.  I also hadn't logged in because I hadn't  ever come to this site before.