# Closing an off-topic question with an open bounty?

Tags: discussion, bounties, vote-to-close

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can we close questions with bounties?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/how-can-we-close-questions-with-bounties)

[This open-ended shopping question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713511/resources-to-start-learning-html-and-css-the-modern-way) doesn't belong on SO, but I can't close it.  This is because it has an open bounty.  Can a bounty really act as invincibility shield for questions that should be closed?  This seems not ideal.

Is there anything I can do aside from waiting out the bounty?

(Also, the genesis of my wanting to close it is because crappy off-topic answers are polluting the new answers to old questions queue)

Comment: Yep, bounties are the last line of defense.

Comment: You flag for moderator attention using the "other" reason and explain the situation.

Comment: @ben, thanks, I've done that.  Hopefully the mods have more powers in this regard. :)

Comment: A bounty will indicate an answer is desired by a wider group of people. Thus, it becomes much harder to close it, since it is desired. (still, not impossible)

Comment: @Telthien - Not if the bounty was offered by the question OP.

Comment: @ben, thanks, totally a dup of that.  (sorry I didn't find it myself)

Comment: They definitely have more powers @kirk, it's a little annoying but understandable that we can't just close it but the questions I've flagged with bounties have been closed in fairly short order (and this'll be quicker as you've posted it on meta!)