# Request to mark bountied question as a duplicate of another

Tags: discussion, support, bounties, duplicate-questions, declined-flags

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286934/how-do-i-implement-jquery-ui-in-a-chrome-extension)'s problem is identical to [this one (with accepted answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599365/google-chrome-extension-popup-page-not-showing-correctly?lq=1)*. However, I cannot vote to close it as a duplicate, because there's a bounty on it.

According to [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/how-can-we-close-questions-with-bounties), the only way to close the question is to flag it, so I did:

> This question is an exact duplicate of [google chrome extension- popup page not showing correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11599365). The problem in both questions is the enforcement of the Content Security Policy, which disables inline scripts. I can't close the question because of the bounty, so please remove the bounty and add "[Duplicate].

It was declined:

> declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

Why?

<sub>* For those who are not familiar with the topic:</sub>
The problem in both questions is that the OP expected code between `<script>` and `</script>` to be evaluated.
In both cases, the answer is that the code does not execute because of the [Content Security policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html), and that the correct way to solve it is to move the code to an external file, and include it using `<script src="file.js"></script>`.

---

EDIT: From the replies so far, it seems that flagging for closure is inappropriate, even if the question is an obvious duplicate. Is it?

Comment: Could have been a mistake; moderators are human too, apparently. :-)

Comment: [`[status-completed]` by casperOne ♦](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15286934/revisions)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there was an **exception** thrown in one of the **human exception handlers** :).

To be honest, I think that, for at least the duration of the bounty that it should remain open. As long as somebody isn't repeatedly asking the same question, then awarding a bounty/answer to the same user, we can live with the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the thing--does this really require moderator attention?  Duplicate hunting is more of a community activity than a moderator activity.  You can't ask a janitor to evaluate two questions on technical grounds to determine if they are similar enough to be marked as duplicates.

[Duplication isn't necessarily a *bad* thing](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/) and therefore doesn't really require moderators to come rushing in to hose everybody down.  The community is more than capable of policing this.  (This doesn't cover reposts, as that definitely requires mod attention).

The fact that there is a bounty does seem to suggest that, yes, in this case mods need to be involved because you can't close questions with bounties.  However, look at it from the other side... You're a user who answers a bountied question, taking your own time to craft a good answer in the hopes that your answer will be highest voted and selected as correct.  Now some jerk mod comes in and closes the question on you just because the question is slightly similar to another one.

Is that a good or bad experience for that user?  Is it really important enough to break a bounty to mark a decent question as a duplicate?

Comment: But the answer from the other question can be copy-pasted verbatim to the bountied question. As a user (from the OPs perspective), I would be glad to get my answer *and* my bounty refunded. The bountied question does not have any correct answer. Please read the answer on the duplicate, and with that knowledge, compare both questions. They're almost identical.

Comment: @RobW: I'm not saying you're *wrong* about the duplication of questions, I'm saying that 1. it doesn't rise to the level that requires moderator attention 2. it would cause more harm than good to remove the bounty in order to close as duplicate.

Comment: @JeremyBanks: Seems like I was misinformed, a moderator can *only* refund a bounty. My bad.