# Hide the "close" link for questions that have an open bounty

Tags: discussion, bounties, vote-to-close

When a question has an open bounty on it, [it cannot be closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/how-can-we-close-questions-with-bounties). Should the close link be hidden in these cases?

Comment: That would be more confusing that having a message explain *why* that question can't be closed.  We'll just see lots of meta questions asking why such and such a question doesn't have a close link.