# Cannot flag as duplicate if there is a bounty

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, flags, duplicate-questions

I just tried to flag [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/509330/execute-single-program-on-boot-no-menus) on AskUbuntu as a duplicate. However, due to it having a bounty on it, I cannot. I just get this error:

[image]

Even if the general StackExchange policy is to *not* close questions with a bounty on them, it should be possible to at least mark them as duplicates and add the flag somewhere. I don't think it's reasonable to have to wait 7 days just to mark it as a duplicate.

In 7 days, I'll have forgotten about this question anyways, I'll forget to mark it and it won't show up as "possible duplicate", just as a "linked question".

**EDIT: To clarify: I do not necessarily want to vote to close the question.** I'd just like the box to appear just like it does on this post:

[image]

And as far as I know, "flagging for moderator attention" does **not** do this.

Comment: There it is: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/how-can-we-close-questions-with-bounties

Comment: Can a moderator actually add the duplicate flag and link the question? Or can they only close the question?

Comment: You can link them too using a comment. Mods close.

Comment: I know that I can link them. But that's not the same kind of link as a duplicate link...

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: The links to duplicates usually show up at the top of the question once it is closed. There can be more than one such question linked there. Linked questions just appear in the sidebar.

Comment: So you have to vote to close to see them on top eventually. And you can't while having a bounty on it.

Comment: You see that box at the top of this post? I want that box to appear. I don't necessarily want to vote to close the question, as the very question you've linked says that SE policy is that that is not possible.

Comment: Well, than at most it is a feature request, not a bug.

Comment: @JeremieMiserez only the author of the question (you, in this case) see the "This question may already have an answer here" banner. Nobody else, until the question is actually closed as duplicate. So this pretty much renders your report/request quite pointless as far as I can tell.

Comment: +1 to what @ShadowWizard said.  I'd just add a comment on the duplicate with a link to the question you feel already answers it.  That would both ping the owner via their inbox and add a link in the sidebar - should be enough attention.

Answer (score 1):

If I recall, flagging for closure (including duplicate) puts the question in the Close Votes review queue. Since it has a bounty and can't be closed, there's not much point in doing that.

So I don't think it's a bug.

Instead, use the "Other" option when flagging and explain that the question is a duplicate, which question it's a duplicate of, and that you're flagging it this way because the bounty is preventing closure.

Comment: I don't necessarily want to close it. But I do want the flag to register in the system, so that the question is linked "as a duplicate". I believe they are handled differently from regular "linked" questions.

Comment: You can't flag / vote duplicate question when there is a bounty. Flag 'Other' is your only option.