# Change Close Vote to Mod Flag - Bad Questions with Open Bounty

Tags: feature-request, flags, vote-to-close, bounties

When you first join an SE site, you have the ability to flag a bad question for all of the normal "close vote" reasons.  This is handled as a moderator flag.  However, once you have close vote privileges, most options in the moderator flag menu become "close vote" prompts:

[image: Flag Close]

The official stance on closing bad questions with an open bounty is to flag for moderator attention, get the mod to issue a refund, and then the question can be closed [Official Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/27103/275463).  For clarification, executing a close vote on an open bounty question gives you:

[image: VTConBounty]

It would make sense then to revert back to the original flag menu if the close vote is not allowed on bounty questions.

### 2 Questions:

**When there is an open bounty, can we change the programming of the moderator flag menu to allow moderator flags for any "close vote" reason even when the user has close vote privileges?**

**When there is an open bounty, can we accept all moderator flags (including close reason flags)?**

Comment: I'm... confused. Those flags you show aren't allowed on a question with an open bounty even if you don't have close vote privileges (they push questions to the close vote queue). I think you might be looking for the 'in need of moderator intervention' flag?

Comment: You clicked `flag` not `close` right?

Comment: @rene Yes. I did.

Comment: @hichris123 That is my point.  The only way to close a bounty question is with moderator intervention.  Before you have close vote privileges, you can flag a question for closing based on all the normal close vote reasons.  Hence my [tag:feature-request].

Comment: Ok, I upvoted @hichris123 comment then so we can share our confusion...

Comment: @rene Edited post to try and be more clear.

Comment: @Chrismas007 But you still cannot flag a question for closing if the question has a bounty on it.

Comment: @hichris123 Ah yes, I just tested that on a site where I do not have close vote privs...

Comment: I suspect this will be closed as "working as designed": If someone wants to spend their reputation on keeping a bad question around, so be it. Contributors in good standing (with plenty of reputation to spend on bounties) are unlikely to ask truly terrible questions, whereas bad contributors (who ask bad questions) are unlikely to have much reputation to spend on bounties for their bad questions.

Answer (score -1):

The official source you cite is a six year old post. The sites have grown by orders of magnitude since then. While flagging for mod attention is an option, it would not be correct to say that this is *the* recommended approach.

Another approach is to wait until the bounty expires, and close then. This allows the decision to be reached by multiple users instead of a single mod. Moderators defer to the community regarding closing, as long as this is practical. An exception would be a question so inappropriate that it needs to be out of the way ASAP.

So, I don't support the idea of software suggesting mod flags whenever someone tries to close a question with a bounty.

Comment: Oh, when I flag in these cases I ask to only remove the bounty, leaving the closing to 3K-ers. Do you consider that to be wrong as well?

Comment: I don't consider it wrong. People are free to ask anything. I consider it wrong to have software automatically pushing users toward mod flagging.

Comment: Sorry, but waiting for a bounty to expire in 7 days should not ever be considered a valid option, I cannot agree with this answer.