# How do to deal with a spam question that has a bounty on it?

Tags: discussion, bounties, duplicate-questions, spam

Whilst reading this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38204214/how-to-integrate-imagemagick-to-magento-site/38479100#38479100 something felt odd about it, and I decided to Google about it, just to my surprise to encounter the same question already asked two times on Magento site:

[How to integrate ImageMagick to magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/126123/how-to-integrate-imagemagick-to-magento)

[gd library or image magick - which is better](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/126175/gd-library-or-image-magick-which-is-better)

And already asked on Stack Overflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38435734/how-to-implement-imagemagick-feature-in-magento-site

I've already flagged it as spam, but, how will the reviewer know that that is actually the case?

Comment: Misusing the spam flag is a very serious issue. Don't do that!

Comment: @Sha How about "abusive" flag for the reposts?

Comment: @nicael still doesn't justify such a flag. Just ordinary "off topic" flag where it doesn't belong, maybe custom flag so that moderator will warn the user.

Comment: I've declined your flag because just a link to a meta post is not a valid flag. I came here with no context and no idea why you flagged the post or what you wanted the moderator to do. Please be explicit in your flags, explain what is wrong and what we need to do.

Comment: Thank you @MartijnPieters, and apologize for the low quality of the comment. Will keep in mind if every will flag again

Comment: I've now deleted the SO copy of the post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not spam – it doesn't *advertise* anything. Yes, they contain a link to the user's site, but the question is *about* an issue they encounter while developing the site. Therefore, a spam flag will be declined.

It *is* a case of [cross-posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) (posting the same question on different Stack Exchange sites); it must be the same user, even though the accounts are not linked.

If you encounter a question with an active bounty which needs to be closed, or a case of cross-posting (even without bounties involved), use a [custom moderator flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/how-can-we-close-questions-with-bounties) explaining the situation.

Comment: I have doubts ... the pattern is so strong that I don't call it an accident they link to every website they work on...

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't say it's spam, OP just is trying to solve their problem. But... abuse?

OP posts a question on Jul 5 on Stack Overflow. Then, on Jul 18, they repost the question on Magento. Reposting question to get more attention, even on another site, is not right at all, but let's suppose OP just thought it could be on-topic on both sites and didn't know that cross-posting is discouraged at all.

Though, Jul 18 they *repost* the question on both sites, that's already completely unacceptable. The second question gots closed on Stack Overflow (but upvoted on Magento). Next step is OP starting bounties on two older questions - again not really good, since OP didn't even "notice" comments which said that the question requires the research efforts and attempts to solve the problem.

Both questions should be removed on one site, and one on another site. This should be dealt by an employee, since it requires conforming actions on both of the sites.

Comment: I agree calling it abuse but I would say in this particular case it is spam. They link to every website they are working on, by the looks of it as a contracter. That is at least an affiliation that goes unmentioned. Linking to those sites might be beneficial for their customers. It is not an accident, almost every other post follows the same pattern.

Comment: @rene What affiliation? Saying that a site does belong to someone else is not really relevant (since the owner of the site should know someone is working on it, right?..), but the question remains.