# Why can you go through the motions to close a question with a bounty?

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, bounties, migration

I note that the question about closing questions with bounties has come up on various occasions, with the ['official' question here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/how-can-we-close-questions-with-bounties).

However, I don't think anyone has responded to a little comment made there that one can still go through the entire set of clicks to close such a question, even to the point of selecting which site to migrate a question to, before being told "you can't close questions with open bounties".

I just ran into this behavior in an attempt to suggest [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3226829/fifa19-overall-rating-is-higher-for-specific-country) belongs on a different SE network.  It doesn't really hurt me personally if I can't today, but the overall mechanism seems to be an overlooked bug.  I figured I'd ask about it in case there is something I'm missing about why it's possible to go all the way down the rabbit trail before being told "sorry"; surely the "close" functionality should just be made impossible during a bounty, if that is the official policy?

Comment: I've likewise been frustrated by the waste of my effort to close a bounty question.  the pop-up message informing a user that "you can't close questions with open bounties"  should pop-up the moment at which a user initially clicks "close", or after clicking "flag" followed by "this question should be closed because...".

Comment: I'm tempted to offer a bounty on this question :)

Comment: Cue someone finding a duplicate then getting frustrated they can't close?

Comment: It possibly has to do with the added complexity of getting all that additional checking into the UI, and spending the development and testing effort for something that rarely occurs when there are many other places that effort can be spent that would have a greater impact.  You still can't remove any of the existing checks (e.g. one could vote to close a question that doesn't have a bounty listed when you load it, but does once you VTC).

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm fair point for the developer time and energy.  I'm just looking for someone official to admit that - not that even that is probably worth their time or energy :) but it was fun offering a bounty for the first time.