# When a bounty is returned by moderator, is this shown in the revision history (timeline, SEDE)?

Tags: support, bounties, data-explorer, revisions-list, timeline

Moderators can refund the bounty to the users offering bounties. (However, this only happens in some rare situations.) If that happens, can we see this in the timeline and revision history? Is some event recorded in the PostHistory table in the [Data Explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info)?

Based on what I read in the FAQ post "[How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065)", it seems that the bounty simply disappears without any trace. But it is just mentioned in passing, I wanted to get some confirmation on this.

> However, [diamond moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/who-are-the-diamond-moderators-and-what-is-their-role) can clear bounties, which would effectively remove the bounty and clear its history. The bounty owner's reputation would be recalculated as if they had never placed that bounty. This would then allow it to be closed, migrated, or deleted like any other question. ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/why-cant-we-close-questions-with-bounties/27103#27103))

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this is visible in the timeline as a 'notice removed' event. [Example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/314981/timeline#history_b94e19a9-31e9-44cb-a1a8-19f4070c894d):

[image]

These events are also visible in the [revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/314981/revisions).

The 'bounty start vote' is deleted and [does not appear in SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1236723).

However, there is a post notice of type 11 ('Draw attention', one of the bounty reasons) which is created by the bounty giver and deleted by the moderator who cancelled the bounty; see [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1236725).

[image]

That means it's possible to get a [list of cancelled bounties](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1236737/cancelled-bounties); more than hundred on Meta Stack Exchange so far.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and especially for the query listing all refunded bounties. (I was wondering whether it is possible to get something like that.) I have made [a slight modification of your query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1236740/bounties-cancelled-by-moderators) which also shows links to the revision history and the timeline - in this context, people might be interested in them, so it might be useful to have a quick access.

Comment: That's a good addition, I've updated my query as well (I don't like bare URLs ...) I've explicitly chosen not to show the moderator cancelling the bounty.

Comment: Just a minor question about the query. The part `pn.DeletionUserId != -1` is there to omit the bounties where no answer was selected, right?

Comment: @Martin I don't remember, but if I remove it: https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1254226 a lot of bounties which ended regularly are included. Perhaps all where the bounty wasn't awarded in the end?