# Why is the user who ended a bounty shown in SEDE differently from the timeline and the revision history?

Tags: bug, bounties, data-explorer, revisions-list, timeline

Recently I looked at situations where the PostNotices table shows a different OwnerUserId and DeletionUserId. This was based on Glorfindel's advice, who suggested this as a way to find bounties which were cancelled (refunded) by a moderator: [When a bounty is returned by moderator, is this shown in the revision history (timeline, SEDE)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347656#347657)

I have run the following query on Mathematics: https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1236765/bounties-cancelled-by-moderators When looking in columns with users, sometimes the user shown there an the end of a bounty (i.e., the user who removed the notice) isn't a moderator. Moreover, in those instance the timeline the revision history show the same user - which is different from the information obtained from PostNotices table. In order to make them easier to find, here is a query which is [restricted to these instances](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1236827/query-for-bug-report). The posts in question are: [3465251](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3465251/revisions), [3354783](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3354783/revisions), [2783577](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2783577/revisions), [236640](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/236640/revisions), [2651720](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2651720/revisions), [979747](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/979747/revisions).

I did not find such instances on other sites. (I have to admit that I did not look for many of them. Moreover, it is much easier to notice this on a site I am familiar with, since I know who are present and past moderators.)

I have tagged this as [bug](/questions/tagged/bug). If I simply overlooked something, I have no problem with changing the tag to [support](/questions/tagged/support).

EDIT: A moderator on Mathematics Stack Exchange [confirmed in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54337077#54337077) that some merges have been done.

Comment: Maybe those were users merged during the bounty period?  I see that is the same guess @Glorfindel made in SEDE chat ...

Comment: Since the previous comment mentions a discussion in chat about this, I will also include a link: https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/conversation/bounties-cancelled-by-moderators

Comment: The posts you link here show that an answer was chosen in their timeline...

Comment: @Luuklag That's exactly the point. For example, [timeline of this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3465251/timeline) shows all bounty-related actions (start/end, notice added/removed) associated with the user Yannic Muller. However, the linked SEDE query shows two different user ids (in OwnerUserId and DeletionUserId).

Comment: The Ids shown in SEDE are indeed deleted user Ids from user merges, though I have no idea where they're coming from. It's possible they just aren't updated on merge because they don't get displayed anywhere and no one has ever noticed.